# What is the orange color code of StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion

In hex, what is the value for the "orange" of StackOverflow?

Comment: [This](http://www.paulnettle.com/pub/FluidStudios/Tools/Fluid_Studios_Color_Picker_2.5.zip) is how you fish

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
#FF9900
```

[Color Cop](http://colorcop.net/) to the rescue! Well I guess you could look at the source (CSS) too but this is easier.

Comment: Indeed. I was looking at the CSS but aftwe a looooong search ( about 32 secs ) I decided to post

Comment: Google Chrome says you're correct: background-color: rgb(255, 153, 0);

Answer (score 15):

**UPDATE 2021:**

According to their [Brand Guidelines](https://stackoverflow.design/brand/colors/) the color is now:

[image]

```
#F48024
```